# Android Application Library Project Where's the Jar?

Tags: android, eclipse

I just created android library project, marked as library but bin does not have jar files of the java classes.  Looked thru the project properties, don't see where you set for compilation build to output a jar file?  I want the jar to auto create every time project is built.

Answer (score 1):

> Looked thru the project properties, don't see where you set for compilation build to output a jar file?

An Android library project does not "output a JAR file", per se.

If the library project is used by another Android project, the build tools will create a JAR file containing the compiled Java classes, but this JAR file is not designed for distribution. Instead, those same build tools will incorporate that JAR file, plus the library project's resources, as part of the host app's build process.